# Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3 (revision: 29.0.3)". shows while opens android studio first time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I installed Android studio 4.1 and open my project structure first time. But it shows gradle sync started and display the msg like Preparing

> Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3 (revision: 29.0.3)

But I waited for more than 2 hours and it shows the same message and gradle sync keep on continuing. Can anybody has any idea about this?

Also in task manager "***OpenJDK platform Binary***" is running along with Android studio process.

Please find the below response what I got it in android studio

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 2 s 891 ms

> Configure project :app
> app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0'.
> File C:\Users\abcuser.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3 in C:\Users\abcuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
> License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3 accepted. Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.3 (revision: 29.0.3)".

Thanks
Ak

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of running processes?

Comment: @kfir88 update the running processes in the quesiton

Answer (score 0):

Close android studio, stop everything then relaunch android studio again...